# C#, Getting each specific number(s) from 0 to 9999

Tags: c#, loops

again. I'm probably asking a simple question. Okay, let me begin;

I want to get each number from 0 to 9999. Each specific number that is. Why? Well, I need it for case numbers. Here is what I have so far;

```
            for (int i = 0; i < 9999; ++i)
            {
                if (line.Contains("if(intid == " + i + ")") || line.Contains("if intid == " + i) && !line.EndsWith(" then"))
                {
                    ErrorBox.Items.Add("ERROR: You're missing then near " + line + " TIME: " + DateTime.Now);
                }
            }
```

What I have above will only get the last number which is 9999, but I want each specific number 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc. "i" should retrieve each and every number up to 9999. But, the "for" loop isn't working properly.

Answer (score 0):

The loop looks fine to me, I'd say the issue is with your if statement.  Try this:

```
if (line.Contains("if(intid == " + i + ")") || line.Contains("if intid == " + i) && !line.EndsWith(" then"))
{
    ErrorBox.Items.Add("ERROR: You're missing then near " + line + " TIME: " + DateTime.Now);
}
else
  ErrorBox.Items.Add("Not an error");
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got i declared as an int; however the string.contains method expects to see a string.

So where you've got i in your contains, make this i.ToString() instead:

```
if (line.Contains("if(intid == " + i.ToString() + ")") || line.Contains("if intid == " + i.ToString()) && !line.EndsWith(" then"))
```

I'm not sure why it would work for 9999 but not for the others. Possibly the logic of the || and && ?

Andrew

Comment: Wow, apparently it does see it as a string. Thanks, it worked. It will now get each number. Only one problem is that it doesn't do line.Contains("if(intid == " + i.ToString() + ")" correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have a problem with [prescendence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). && is evaluated before ||. It is like 1 + 2 * 3 equals 7 . You need to add (  ) to evaluate your expression properly. 
(b1 || b2) && b3

EDIT

```
bool b1 = line.Contains("if(intid == " + i + ")");
bool b2 = line.Contains("if intid == " + i);
bool b3 = !line.EndsWith(" then");
```

So write

```
if ((line.Contains("if(intid == " + i + ")") || line.Contains("if intid == " + i)) 
    && !line.EndsWith(" then"))
```